# Ruby on rails multi level route path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have defined a route as per the below but I am getting some errors. Below is the code outlining what is happening

```
namespace :shopping do
  resources :merchants, only: [:index, :show] do
```

Which I was hoping I would be able to use `= link_to shopping_merchant_path(merchant)`

But this is giving me the following error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shopping/merchants", :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Merchant id: 1, name: "52e9689bc89a", featured: false>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

rake routes output

```
Pauls-Air% rake routes | grep shopping_merchant
                          shopping_merchant_products GET    (/:locale)/shopping/merchants/:merchant_id/products(.:format)                  shopping/products#index {:locale=>/en/}
                           shopping_merchant_product GET    (/:locale)/shopping/merchants/:merchant_id/products/:id(.:format)              shopping/products#show {:locale=>/en/}
                                  shopping_merchants GET    (/:locale)/shopping/merchants(.:format)                                        shopping/merchants#index {:locale=>/en/}
                                   shopping_merchant GET    (/:locale)/shopping/merchants/:id(.:format)                                    shopping/merchants#show {:locale=>/en/}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a parameter to `shopping_merchant_path` in your view, as your merchant is being passed through as `locale` (which is not default behaviour - do you have some locale gem installed?) what is the output of `rake routes | grep shopping_merchant` ?

Comment: are you setting params[:locale] anywhere

Comment: you need to set it or rails will assume :id to be :locale

Comment: locale is set within my application controller

Comment: this is the only link_to within the app that doesnt appear to be working

Comment: Does your `shopping/merchants` controller inherit from `ApplicationController` OK? If locale isn't being set maybe it is getting confused.

Comment: im currently doing this `class Shopping::MerchantsController < ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

As onikron suggested you need to pass parameter to your `route`

```
= link_to shopping_merchant_path(@merchant)
```

I think you are trying something like

```
= link_to shopping_merchant_path(locale: @merchant)
```

> :locale=>#< Merchant id: 1, name: "52e9689bc89a", featured: false>

No need of `:locale` in link_to

Comment: :locale isnt being passed in the link_to as you can see from above

Comment: as its suspicious rails is moving `@merchant` in `:locale`

Comment: Its problem with routes

Comment: rails is assuming @merchant as :locale

Comment: @Deepak this is the scope within my routes, once I comment this out it appears to work `scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do`